# colorbox don't have height at second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox on multiple links to load inline content, like this :

```
jQuery('#atelier .list .block a').each(function(){
    var idContent = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var htmlContent = jQuery(idContent).html();
    jQuery(this).colorbox({
        inline: true,
        html: htmlContent,
        scrolling:false,
        width:ateWidth,
        opacity:0.6,

    });
});
```

the first call work well, and display the content of my div. But if i click another link after closing the first one, i end with a 0px height colorbox, even if the content of my is in cboxLoadedContent. i tried this solution :

```
jQuery('#atelier .list .block a').each(function(){
    var idContent = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var htmlContent = jQuery(idContent).html();
    jQuery(this).colorbox({
        inline: true,
        html: htmlContent,
        scrolling:false,
        width:ateWidth,
        opacity:0.6,
        onComplete: function(){
            jQuery.colorbox.resize();
        }

    });
});
```

and the same with a correct height in the resize function, but with no effects. The problem happens in all IE, chrome, FF.. no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The inline and html properties are exclusive (pick one or the other, not both), so that may have something to do with it.  But this is all a bit more convoluted than it needs to be.  Try this:

```
jQuery('#atelier .list .block a').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).colorbox({
        inline: true,
        href: $(this).attr('href'),
        scrolling:false,
        width:ateWidth,
        opacity:0.6,
        onComplete: function(){
            jQuery.colorbox.resize();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the cleaner structure. The error was mine, the container called was hidden. a css('display','block') in the onLoad function solved it.